# Fetch timezone as per user location and save it in database in Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.2 and trying to get a user location and user timezone after logged in the app and want to store in the database so I can prefer that data for further process.

Can anyone help me out to solve this problem.